# How to add user to a role when registering

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a role called "Customer", I wish to add users who register to be to automatically added to that role. At the moment I can only assign users to roles by using ASP.net Web Site Administration Tool.
If it helps: I'm using the default login.aspx and register.aspx files from Account folder in vb web profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the username, you can just use:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole("NewUsername", "Customer");
```

I'm not familiar with the Account folder in the VB web profile. Does it use a `CreateUserWizard` control? If so, you can get the username from that and handle the [CreatingUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.creatinguser.aspx) event.

```
Dim uName As String = registrationWizard.UserName.ToString   
Roles.AddUserToRole(uName, "Customer")
```